# Using Xpath expression and checking element's count

Tags: php, xpath

I am web scraping a table with Xpath and matching `TR`'s `tds` but the problem in this situation. some of TR has one `td` so I need to eliminate those. But with that elimination I am having a quiet problem.

For example:

```
    $getTR = $path->query("//table[@class='bgc_line']/tr");
    foreach($getTR as $tr){
        if ($tr->length == 2) {
            $route = $path>query("//table[@class='bgc_line']/tr/td[1]");
            foreach ($route as $td1) {
                $property[] = trim($td1->nodeValue);
            }

            $route = $path->query("//table[@class='bgc_line']/tr/td[2]");
            foreach ($route as $td2) {
                $value[] = trim($td2->nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

So my usage of `if` isn't exactly right. But is there other way to do this? Because I have two expression and first Xpath's count is different then second. That's why I can't match the Data with each other. you can see the table [here](https://mecsumai.com/bkn-summary/?bid=16076001&bg1=026937&bg2=dce8e2&wdt=100%25&aln=center).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
table[@class='bgc_line']/tr[count(td) > 1]
```

To get table rows only if they have more than one child `td`